# angular transclude and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

how do I transclude following code, using the MyDirective as an directive!

```
<div my-directive title="test">
    <div ng-repeat="test in dataInController">
          <div ng-bind="test.title"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to alter the output of the element to

```
<div>
    <div class="header">test</test>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- original html content of the directive -->
        <div ng-repeat="test in dataInController">
            <div ng-bind="test.title"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to play around with transclude with no luck!

any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Tried Tomer [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996041/angular-transclude-and-ng-repeat#answer-32996720) without any luck

thnx
c_bb

Comment: show us your directive code, as well as the current template your are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
module.directive("myDirective", function () {
                    return {
                        template: '<div><div class="header">{{title}}</div><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
                        transclude: true,
                        scope: { title: '@' }
                    };
                });
```

Comment: Hi Tomer .. thank you for the quick reply .. the repeat is not added after running it through the directive ... and that is my main issue.

Comment: @user2083317, what makes you say that the repeat is not added? Does it not show the values when transcluded?

Comment: The div that has the repeat inside is blank ... so it comes out <div ng-transclude></div>

Comment: @user2083317, when you say it's "blank", are you inspecting the DOM in the directive, to come to that conclusion? Because it would be very odd that `ng-transclude` does not actually transclude (unless you have some error in the console)

Comment: the html is added as it is in the template and nothing is transcluded, and I have no errors

Comment: thank you for the solution, I had missed a small detail in my code .. I was blind, but now I see :-)

Answer (score -1):

See this Code:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function()
{
  return{
     template : '<div><div class="header">{{title}}</div><div class="content"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div></div>',
     transclude : true,
     scope : {
       title : "@"
     },
     link : function(scope, ele, attr){

     }

   }
 });
```

[see this code](http://plnkr.co/edit/H5IvTOWce36G8hopKETa?p=preview)

Comment: no luck ... just ended up with '<ng-transclude> </ng-transclude>' inside the div with content class!